# How can I get an average for a row in a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Have a matrix report now that has 
Position, Hours and Wages for a location for a month.
There may be any number of locations...that's why I'm starting with a Matrix report...the user may chose up to 50 locations to view.

```
    
                   Location 1         Location 2
               Total Hrs Amount     Total Hrs Amount
    Position1  441.68    $4,201.46  556.73    $6,103.67
```

We would like to get an average by position for that month, like so

```
                   Location 1         Location 2            Avg
               Total Hrs Amount     Total Hrs Amount       Avg Hrs 
    Position1  441.68    $4,201.46  556.73    $6,103.67    499.20
```

Can't quite figure out how to get this to work in SSRS 2005...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a calculated field with formula (rs!localtion1Hrs + rs!location2hrs) / 2.

OR

The query used to show the report can have this field as calculated column.

Comment: just edited the question -- added this -- There may be any number of locations...that's why I'm starting with a Matrix report...the user may chose up to 50 locations to view....

Comment: what is the SQL behind source data?

Comment: I guess matrix report should have an option to add additional summary columns. Sorry, its been some time that I worked on SSRS

Comment: Look at this url - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334.aspx . It tries to add extra columns towards the end to do a summary

Comment: That's only for SSRS 2008...we're on SSRS 2005...the corresponding article for SSRS 2005 here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334(SQL.90).aspx doesn't have a way to do what's in the SSRS 2008 article...I believe that the only aggregate function available in a SSRS 2005 matrix is the Sum function

Comment: Could you show the SQL query that is used as the dataset for this report?

Comment: It's based on a complex view, but it really just boils down to this... select location, position, year, month, totalhours, amount from myPayrollTable. For the dataset for the report, I use a sproc to call the view that has parameters on year, month and location...I pass in a year and a month and multiple locations

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I've solved this by using the following as the DataSet for the report and using a matrix in the report layout.

Basically I did what shahkalpesh said above..."The query used to show the report can have this field as calculated column."

```
select 
        'Avg' as LocationID, 
        'Avg' as Description, 
        AccountDesc, 
        @PayrollYear as Year,
        @PayrollMonth as Month,
        avg(s.TotalHrs) as TotalHrs, 
        avg(s.Amount) as Amount from 
(
    select LocationID, 'Avg' as Description, AccountDesc, 
    @PayrollYear as Year, @PayrollMonth as Month,       
    sum(TotalHrs) as TotalHrs,
    sum(Amount) as Amount from vwPayroll
    where LocationID in (select value from dbo.ParmsToList(@PayrollLocIds)) 
    and Year = @PayrollYear and Month = @PayrollMonth
    group by LocationID, AccountDesc, Year, Month
) as s
group by AccountDesc

union all

select 
        LocationID, 
        Description, 
        AccountDesc, 
        Year, 
        Month, 
        Sum(TotalHrs) as TotalHrs, 
        Sum(Amount) as Amount 
from vwPayroll
where LocationID in (select value from dbo.ParmsToList(@PayrollLocIds)) 
and Year = @PayrollYear and Month = @PayrollMonth
group by LocationID, Description, AccountDesc, Year, Month
```

Comment: If this is part of a stored proc, you could dump the results of the query into a temp table. And use the temp table to do a UNION for average (instead of running the query with SUM(...) twice).

Comment: understood...after I getting it working, I'll refactor for performance...thanks for your help....